# Почему {} работает быстрее, чем dict()

Tags: python

Никак не могу понять почему так происходит. Если обратить к исходникам `CPython`, то там можно увидеть, что обе сущности эквивалентны и представляются в виде массива. Это значит, что вызов `dict()` не должен отличасть по скорость от `{}`.

В качестве эксперимента (для того, чтобы убедиться, что это одна и та же сущность) попробовал сделать так:

```
class Some({}.__class__):
    def hello(self):
        {}.__init__(self)
        print('Hi!')

some = Some()
some['one'] = 1

print(some['one'])
some.hello()
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
1
Hi!
```

Что и следовало ожидать.

Измерял скорость операций не самым надежным способом, но довольно показательным:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("{}")
0.058351269999548094
>>> timeit("dict()")
0.12427372599995579
```

Не могли вы подсказать почему `{}` в 2,5 раза быстрее `dict()` ?

Comment: Я не вижу здесь теста скорости {}/dict(). Как вы определили эту разницу? Прогревали ли вы виртуальную машину перед бенчмарком?

Comment: @Etki к сожалению пока не умею пользоваться бенчмарком...

Comment: Не имеет смысла измерять производительность сломанного кода. Уберите class Some... пример—он здесь ни при чём. Используйте слово "словарь", а не "массив" в Питоне для подобных объектов

Comment: @jfs пример не для теста скорости, а для того, чтобы убедиться, что это одна и та же сущность

Comment: @faoxis вы на заголовок вопроса посмотрите. Вопрос именно о скорости. Ваш пример ничего не доказывает—он сломан

Comment: @faoxis https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быстрее потому, что `{}` - это встроенная в питон синтаксическая конструкция.

А когда вы используете `dict()`, то интерпретатору надо ещё пробежаться по пространству имён, чтобы найти этот самый `dict`.

Но вообще, когда пишут на питоне, то обычно не обращают большого внимания на быстродействие, так как в данном случае важнее скорость создания программы. Если же **категорично** именно быстродействие, то лучше обращать своё внимание к языку "**C**", либо в качестве создания модуля для питона у узкого места, либо в качестве самостоятельной программы.

Comment: Скорее всего `LOAD_GLOBAL` в байт-коде как раз то, о чем Вы говорите.

Comment: Ну а global - это что, по вашему?

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, создание пустого словаря, используя специальный синтаксис, быстрее чем по имени:

```
>>> import timeit 
>>> "%.2f \xb5s" % min(timeit.repeat("dict()"))
'0.45 µs'
>>> "%.2f \xb5s" % min(timeit.repeat("{}"))
'0.28 µs'
```

Можно на байт-код посмотреть:

```
>>> import dis 
>>> dis.dis(lambda: {})
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(lambda: dict())
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (dict)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Если dict имя не переопределено, то одинаковые объекты возвращаются в обоих случаях:

```
>>> type({})
<class 'dict'>
>>> type(dict())
<class 'dict'>
>>> {} == dict()
True
```

В реальном коде, если только вам profiler не сказал, что именно в создании пустого словаря узкое место, не следует выбирать между этими конструкциями по быстроте завершения этого теста.

Comment: "не следует выбирать между этими конструкциями по быстроте завершения этого теста", но почему ? Если `{}` работает быстрее, то логичнее было бы убрать все `dict()` и писать `{}` ?

Comment: @faoxis покажите пример реального кода, где создайте пустого словаря является узким местом. Я почти всегда использую `{}` для создания пустого словаря, но это не имеет никакого отношения к скорости конструкции. Не пытайтесь микро-оптимизациями заниматься и тем более в Питоне.

Comment: аналогичный вопрос - перед тестом делался прогрев?

Comment: @Etki это бессмысленный вопрос в данном контексте.

Comment: "Если `{}` работает быстрее, то логичнее было бы убрать все `dict()` и писать `{}` ?" - я обычно не помню (и не пытаюсь запомнить) что создается с помощью пустого `{}` - словарь или сет, и чтобы не сомневаться всегда явно пишу `dict()` или `set()`. А оптимизировать имеет смысл только если это действительно узкое место.

Comment: тогда это бессмысленный бенчмарк

Comment: @Etki: не понимаете о чём говорите.

Comment: @jfs допустим у меня есть цикл из 10к итераций. В каждой итерации я создаю словарь, кладу в него какое-то значение и перехожу к следующей итерации. Если скорость создания словаря через `{}` быстрее на 0,1 секунду, то в итоге программа завершится почти на 17 минут раньше. Может я что-то не так понимаю, но разве такой результат не показательный ?

Comment: Есть мнение, что стоит забыть про dict() и list() при создании словарей и списков: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41017578/is-there-any-reason-in-writing-instead-of-dict

Comment: Смотрите, у вас есть некоторая виртуальная машина, которая выполняет питонячий байткод. Мы не знаем, что у нее внутри, какие оптимизации она может делать или не делать, что может кэшировать, где может провисать. Но мы можем точно утверждать, что а) если результирующий машинный код идентичен, то первые вызовы могут проседать из-за инициализации дополнительных компонентов (при этом не факт, что инициализация закончилась к моменту выполнения кода и не идет в параллель) , б) машина имеет право оптимизировать вызовы на ходу, если увидит горячий код, в) машину могут прерывать другие процессы хоста

Comment: Поэтому да, я утверждаю: мерять первые три вызова - это бесполезно, потому что мы ничего не знаем и не можем утверждать о расходах на инициализацию, равно как и не можем гарантировать, что на эти три вызова не попадет захват ресурсов кем-то другим. Да, набор инструкций с вызовом функции *должен* по определению быть более ресурсоемким вызовом, чем похожий набор инструкций без вызова, но как только это попадает в исполняющую машину - никаких гарантий здесь нет, она имеет право выбрасывать вызов функции, если захочет и если это не повлияет на логику программы.

Comment: @Etki это наглядный пример когда чуть-чуть знания хуже его полного отсутствия. Если вы сомневаетесь в результатах теста, покажите свои цифры для этого случая.

Comment: Я с тем же успехом могу обвинять всех, кто мне не нравится, в наличии эффекта даннинга-крюгера. Я не говорю, что результаты тесты показывают неправду, я говорю, что они не подтверждают ничего, кроме одного конкретного случая; я не понимаю, как это можно отрицать.

Comment: @Etki вас куда-то унесло. Вы спросили про прогрев. Я сказал, что не имеет смысла спрашивать в данном случае (не играет роли здесь и даже если бы играл, то важнее вопросы следовало бы до этого спросить типа: версии ПО, железо какое).

Comment: https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/

Comment: @vadimvaduxa спасибо, ссылка полезная. В Python 3.6 реализация dict поменялась, но выводы по прежнему верны (укороченный путь для `{}` и обычный никак неспециализированный путь по конструкции `dict()` объекта). Я до этого смотрел С код (близко к тому что в статье показано) и почти собрался ответ расширить для полноты. Желающие могут вашу ссылку теперь почитать.